# Invalid CSRF token with edge or iexplore

Tags: symfony, csrf, fosuserbundle, microsoft-edge, symfony-2.8

This website is a Symfony 2.8 using FOSUser.
The login form works well for these browsers:

- chrome
- firefox
- opera

But fails with a "Invalid CSRF token" (in _profiler, tab logs) on:

- edge
- internet explorer

In all these cases, the [same PHP is used to generate the login form](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security/csrf_in_login_form.html).

I can only think of a defect in browser configuration... any clues?

Comment: Did you check in developer tools if the CSRF token is actually in your request?

Comment: I did, and it does (and the _profiler gets it too in Request/Response > Request > POST Parameters). And the value seems to be the same (no space nor hidden character).